# How do I vertically center a container below a navbar without a scrollbar appearing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making an app using Bootstrap 4. This app has a navbar and a container below the navbar. Here is the layout of the app:

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div>
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div id="logo" title="App"/>
                <button aria-controls="navbar-nav" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler collapsed">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-nav" style="--logoHeight:68px;">
                    <div class="mr-auto navbar-nav">
                        <a href="/home" class="nav-link">Menu</a>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="mt-2 container-fluid">
                <div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center vh-100">
                        <div class="container" id="theContainerToCenterVertically">                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

I want to vertically center the the theContainerToCenterVertically div. The current code does that but a scrollbar appears even if the content fits in one page. How can I vertically center that div without a scrollbar appearing if the content fits in one page?

Comment: try `body{overflow: hidden;}` .Use this if and only if you have a page that fits in to a single screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's overflow-hidden class to hide any content that exceeds your page height and not have any scrollbars. And you can use flex to get your content div to fill the available space (and then use h-100 to cause the child elements to fill that space.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid px-0 d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div id="logo" title="App" />
        <button aria-controls="navbar-nav" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler collapsed">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-nav" style="--logoHeight:68px;">
            <div class="mr-auto navbar-nav">
                <a href="/home" class="nav-link">Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-2 flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-4 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <p>
                    This column&rsquo;s content is vertically centered and is hidden if it exceeds the column height.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, eum? Officia, tenetur iste nemo soluta esse nesciunt nostrum quod ut ab rem eaque, facere magnam possimus quia error, praesentium veniam? Quis, iste? Repellat magni eveniet quos minima dignissimos deserunt cupiditate a animi! Repudiandae nobis sequi quas libero aliquam officia dolor, vero quod obcaecati recusandae ut deleniti consequuntur explicabo exercitationem fugiat quidem. Odit iusto voluptatem possimus dicta recusandae soluta odio, natus nobis, earum eos rerum ratione atque temporibus tenetur numquam reiciendis non. Odit adipisci, numquam fuga facere nesciunt aperiam consectetur expedita autem iure incidunt eligendi placeat necessitatibus animi blanditiis aspernatur nostrum.
                </p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <p>This column content is not centered</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used two columns for the content area just as an example. You can use a single `col` or `col-12` if you just need one column.